# ternary operator results a string - i am concatenating those phrases. unable to understand interpretation java

Tags: java

```java
String loggerKey = "srini";
String loggerDescription =  "vas";
System.out.println(loggerKey != null?loggerKey:""+loggerDescription != null?loggerDescription:"");
```

the above code giving me results Srini, where I am expecting Srinivas. but if I modify code to below way I am getting Srinivas as output.

```java
String loggerKey = "srini";
String loggerDescription =  "vas";
System.out.println((loggerKey != null?loggerKey:"")+(loggerDescription != null?loggerDescription:""));
```

how the first snippet is interpreting by java? this is what I am expecting.

```java
String loggerKey = "srini";
String loggerDescription =  "vas";
System.out.println((loggerKey != null?loggerKey:"")+(loggerDescription != null?loggerDescription:""));

String loggerKey = "srini";
String loggerDescription =  "vas";
System.out.println(loggerKey != null?loggerKey:""+loggerDescription != null?loggerDescription:"");
```

**output:**
`srinivas`

Comment: got how is java divided that first snippet and giving me always srini,

loggerKey != null?loggerKey:""+loggerDescription != null?loggerDescription:""  -  in this it is considering   ""+loggerDescription != null?loggerDescription:"" as single statement

Comment: I recommend to **not** use nested ternary expressions, for it makes your code confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Because of operator precedence rules, your compound ternary is actually being evaluated as this:

```
loggerKey != null ? loggerKey : ("" + loggerDescription != null ?
    loggerDescription : "")
```

That is, while the `vas` description would be assigned, it is part of the second else predicate of the first outer ternary statement, and so is skipped, because the key `srini` is not null.

Your solution of placing parentheses around each separate ternary expression is correct, and is one way to resolve your problem.

Comment: and that is being evaluated as `loggerKey != null ? loggerKey : ( ("" + loggerDescription ) != null ?
    loggerDescription : "")` (added parentheses for inner concatenation)

Answer (score 0):

maybe like that?

```
String loggerKey = "srini";
        String loggerDescription =  "vas";
        System.out.println((loggerKey != null?loggerKey:(""+loggerDescription != null?loggerDescription:""));
```

It make sense to read all the expression after the first `:` as one.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are providing the `()`. In java `()` is treated as a block of code and are processed separately.
Also your logic is wrong as well. It should be like below and you don't have to use `()` then:

```
System.out.println(loggerKey != null ? loggerDescription != null ? loggerKey +
 loggerDescription : loggerKey : loggerDescription != null ? loggerDescription : "");
```

For better readability it's:

```
System.out.println(loggerKey != null ? (loggerDescription != null ? loggerKey + 
loggerDescription : loggerKey) : (loggerDescription != null ? loggerDescription : ""));
```